# Opening executable file doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following code that gets executed when I press on a button on the scene:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\ALIENWARE\\Desktop\\CPP_Build\\CPP_Project.exe";
p.Start();
```

The above code works perfectly and the executable file is opened, but when I try to retrieve the same value from a dictionary, it doesn't work. I have the same path stored in a dictionary and when I log it to the console as follow:

```
Debug.Log(projectsNames_Paths["CPP"]);
```

I get the following printed to the console:

[image: Console output]

the problem is that when I replace the code responsible for opening the executable with the following code:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = projectsNames_Paths["CPP"];
p.Start();
```

I get the following error printed to the console:

> Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified.

Note that my dictionary is of type `<string, string>`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please show us how exactly you are filling the Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

The issues is your strings in your dictionary have a double backslash `\\` which is not a valid path

This is evident by the debug string

```
Debug.Log(projectsNames_Paths["CPP"]);
```

[image]

The reason why this works in the first examples is because *string literal* slashes are escaped by adding a slash, which you have done

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\ALIENWARE\\Desktop\\CPP_Build\\CPP_Project.exe";
```

So in reality your string in the first example is compiled to `C:\Users\ALIENWARE\Desktop\CPP_Build\CPP_Project.exe`

In short your dictionary contains paths that have double slashes, remove the double back slashes from the path in the dictionary, they are not valid

Comment: I tried to implement your solution but unfortunately, it didn't work

Comment: @mar when your debug message doesn't have the double slash, your problem should be solved. If its still doesn't work you will likely have a different problem

Comment: But isn't for a string writing `"path\\path"` the same as writing `@"path\path"`?

Comment: @derHugo it is for *string literals*. But you cant pass that in as a string and expect the path to be valid, if you can see my point. The actual string in the dictionary has the double back slash. which is invalid

Comment: I know what a string literal is bu what I mean is: Isn't the double backslash just escaped to a single backslash by c#? So it should result in an equivalent string right? In general I would rather recommend to use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) for building filepaths

Comment: @derHugo if the string actually contains a double slash. ie `FileName = @"C:\\Users\\.."` then we have problem, which is actually what is happening as can be seen by the debug message which has the double slashes

Comment: but OP has it like `"C:\\Users\\ALIENWARE\\Desktop\\CPP_Build\\CPP_Project.exe"` so I would expect these to be escaped

Comment: @derHugo and they are, that example works for OP, the dictionary doesnt, and it contains the double slash

Comment: Oh now I see your point ;) So basically with OP's provided code this is not reproducible

Comment: @derHugo yeah i'm finding the problem even hard to explain, which shows the subtle nature of the problem